# How I can show multiple with respect to count in D3?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, d3.js

Here is an example taken from : http://bl.ocks.org/natemiller/7dec148bb6aab897e561 working fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

svg {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}


.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.y.axis path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.brush .extent {
  stroke: #fff;
  fill-opacity: .125;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 100, left: 40},
    margin2 = {top: 430, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    height2 = 500 - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
    x2 = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),
    y2 = d3.scale.linear().range([height2, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"),
    xAxis2 = d3.svg.axis().scale(x2).orient("bottom"),
    yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");

var brush = d3.svg.brush()
    .x(x2)
    .on("brush", brush);

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .defined(function(d) { return !isNaN(d.temperature); })
    .interpolate("cubic")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.temperature); });

var line2 = d3.svg.line()
    .defined(function(d) { return !isNaN(d.temperature); })
    .interpolate("cubic")
    .x(function(d) {return x2(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) {return y2(d.temperature); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var focus = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var context = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")");

d3.csv("climate4.csv", function(error, data) {

  color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "date"; }));

    data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    });

  var sources = color.domain().map(function(name) {
      return {
        name: name,
        values: data.map(function(d) {
          return {date: d.date, temperature: +d[name]};
        })
      };
    });

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain([d3.min(sources, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(v) { return v.temperature; }); }),
              d3.max(sources, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return v.temperature; }); }) ]);
    x2.domain(x.domain());
    y2.domain(y.domain());

    var focuslineGroups = focus.selectAll("g")
        .data(sources)
      .enter().append("g");

    var focuslines = focuslineGroups.append("path")
        .attr("class","line")
        .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
        .style("stroke", function(d) {return color(d.name);})
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");

    focus.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    focus.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

    var contextlineGroups = context.selectAll("g")
        .data(sources)
      .enter().append("g");

    var contextLines = contextlineGroups.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", function(d) { return line2(d.values); })
        .style("stroke", function(d) {return color(d.name);})
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");

    context.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
        .call(xAxis2);

    context.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x brush")
        .call(brush)
      .selectAll("rect")
        .attr("y", -6)
        .attr("height", height2 + 7);


});

function brush() {
  x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
  focus.selectAll("path.line").attr("d",  function(d) {return line(d.values)});
  focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
  focus.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
}

</script>
```

I am trying to edit it as per my condition, but its not working in my scenario. Here is the code i tried to edit and the sample:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

svg {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}


.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.y.axis path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.brush .extent {
  stroke: #fff;
  fill-opacity: .125;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 100, left: 40},
    margin2 = {top: 430, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    height2 = 500 - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
    x2 = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),
    y2 = d3.scale.linear().range([height2, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"),
    xAxis2 = d3.svg.axis().scale(x2).orient("bottom"),
    yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");

var brush = d3.svg.brush()
    .x(x2)
    .on("brush", brush);

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .defined(function(d) { return !isNaN(d.temperature); })
    .interpolate("cubic")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.temperature); });

var line2 = d3.svg.line()
    .defined(function(d) { return !isNaN(d.temperature); })
    .interpolate("cubic")
    .x(function(d) {return x2(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) {return y2(d.temperature); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var focus = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var context = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")");

d3.csv("{% static 'fera/ASX.csv' %}", function(error, data) {

  color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { console.log(key); return key !== "Date"; }));

    data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.Date = parseDate(d.Date);
    });

  var sources = color.domain().map(function(name) {
      return {
        name: name,
        values: data.map(function(d) {

          return {date: d.Date, temperature: +d[name]};
        })
      };
    });

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain([d3.min(sources, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(v) { return v.temperature; }); }),
              d3.max(sources, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return v.temperature; }); }) ]);
    x2.domain(x.domain());
    y2.domain(y.domain());

    var focuslineGroups = focus.selectAll("g")
        .data(sources)
      .enter().append("g");

    var focuslines = focuslineGroups.append("path")
        .attr("class","line")
        .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
        .style("stroke", function(d) {return color(d.name);})
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");

    focus.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    focus.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

    var contextlineGroups = context.selectAll("g")
        .data(sources)
      .enter().append("g");

    var contextLines = contextlineGroups.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", function(d) { return line2(d.values); })
        .style("stroke", function(d) {return color(d.name);})
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");

    context.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
        .call(xAxis2);

    context.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x brush")
        .call(brush)
      .selectAll("rect")
        .attr("y", -6)
        .attr("height", height2 + 7);


});

function brush() {
  x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
  focus.selectAll("path.line").attr("d",  function(d) {return line(d.values)});
  focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
  focus.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
}

</script>
```

But getting a hell lot of errors:
[image: error images]

The sample data is: [Sample Data](https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/78efda44eeeea63c9516f5f9c07ba4bb)

I am willing to show the complete OHLCV data in the form of multiple lines. Please help me.

Comment: @rioV8 Thank you for reminding me. I almost forgot to remove it. Here the above is the question that I have.

Comment: your `parseDate` format is wrong

Comment: @rioV8 Is it possible I neglect date and draw with the counter numbers?

Comment: Just change the format string to match your date format, you can use the `counter` but then you loose the spacial separation/position of the points, use a linear scale for X and set the domain correct (`d3.extent`).